# Term aggregation consider only the prefix to aggregate

Tags: elasticsearch

In my elastic search documents I have users and some sort of representation of his place in the organization, for instance:
The CEO is position 1
The ones directly under the CEO will be 1/1, 1/2, 1/3, and so on
The ones under 1/1 will be 1/1/1, 1/1/2, 1/2/3, etc

I have an aggregration in which I want to aggregate by VP, so I want everybody under 1/1, 1/2, 1/3.

To do that I created a query like this one:

```
"aggs": {
            "information": {
                "terms":{
                    "field": "position",
                    "script": "_value.replaceAll('(1/1/[0/]*[1-9]).+', '$1')"
                }
```

This would get the prefix and replace by the group in the regex, so everyone would have the same position, then I could make the aggregation. This has a poor performance.

I was thinking about using something like this

```
"aggs": {
            "information": {
                "terms":{
                    "field": "position",
                    "prefix": "1/1/.*'
                }
```

So I would group by everyone that starts with 1/1 (1/1/1/1, 1/1/1/2, 1/1/1/3 would be one group, 1/1/2/1, 1/1/2/2, 1/1/2/3  would be a second group and so on).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you know beforehand that on how deep level you want to run this aggregation, you could simply store these levels at different fields:

```
{
    "name": "Jack",
    "own_level": 4,
    "level_1": "1",
    "level_2": "3",
    "level_3": "2",
    "level_4": null
}
```

But this would require many nested terms aggregations to reproduce the hierarchy. This version would make one such aggregation sufficient:

```
{
    "name": "Jack",
    "own_level": 4,
    "level_1": "1",
    "level_2": "1/3",
    "level_3": "1/3/2",
    "level_4": null
}
```

It also has simpler query filter if you want to focus on people under for example `1/1` by having a filter on field `level_2` and terms aggregation on field `level_3`.

If you don't know the maximum level of the hierarchy you can use nested documents like this, but then queries and aggregations get a bit more complex:

```
{
    "name": "Jack",
    "own_level": 4,
    "bosses": [
        {
            "level": 1,
            "id": "1"
        },
        {
            "level": 2,
            "id": "1/3"
        },
        {
            "level": 3,
            "id": "1/3/2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Oh I realized only now that his was asked so long ago, well I hope this info is still useful.